# How to get rid of error "unavalability of vmlinux" when creating a kernel module

Tags: c, linux, module, linux-kernel

I was given an assignment for school to create a kernel module that accesses the task_struct with my PID. I am receiving an error (I don't think its an error but I don't know what else to call it) that says, `Skipping BTF generation for /home/dpb/Documents/CSE_420/p4/try2/mymodule2.ko due to unavailability of vmlinux` and from searching online I cant even figure out what vmlinux is in this context.

Here is my code...

````
```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>

#include <linux/pid_namespace.h>

int p_id;
struct pid *pid_struct;
struct task_struct *task;


/* Meta Information */
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Devin 4 GNU/Linux");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("A hello world LKM");

/* This funciton is called when the module is loaded into the kernel */
static int __init ModuleInit(void) {
    pid_struct = find_get_pid(p_id);
    task = pid_task(pid_struct,PIDTYPE_PID);    
    
    printk("PID: \n");
    printk("Name: %s\n", task->comm);
    printk("Total Pages in KB: \n");
    printk("File System Name: \n");
    return 0;
}

/* This funciton is called whe the module is removed fromt he kernel */
static void __exit ModuleExit(void) {
    printk("Bye!\n");
}

module_init(ModuleInit);
module_exit(ModuleExit);

```#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>

#include <linux/pid_namespace.h>

int p_id;
struct pid *pid_struct;
struct task_struct *task;


/* Meta Information */
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Devin 4 GNU/Linux");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("A hello world LKM");

/* This funciton is called when the module is loaded into the kernel */
static int __init ModuleInit(void) {
    pid_struct = find_get_pid(p_id);
    task = pid_task(pid_struct,PIDTYPE_PID);    
    
    printk("PID: \n");
    printk("Name: %s\n", task->comm);
    printk("Total Pages in KB: \n");
    printk("File System Name: \n");
    return 0;
}

/* This funciton is called whe the module is removed fromt he kernel */
static void __exit ModuleExit(void) {
    printk("Bye!\n");
}

module_init(ModuleInit);
module_exit(ModuleExit);
```
````

I receive the error when I run my make file...

````
```
KERNEL_SOURCE := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PWD := $(shell pwd)
obj-m += mymodule2.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```
````

Everyone in my class that I have spoken with never ran into this issue, can someone explain what unavalability of vmlinux means so I can try and figure out why my module wont finish executing when ran with the command line `sudo insmod mymodule2.ko`.